# ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest not executed by PhpUnit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have implemented some of Symfony's [best practices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/tests.html), that is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $this->client->followRedirects();
    }

    /**
     * @param $url
     * @dataProvider urlProvider
     */
    public function testPageIsSuccessful($url)
    {
        $this->client->request('GET', $url);

        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
    }

    public function urlProvider()
    {
        return [
            ['/'],
            ['/en']
        ];
    }
}
```

Yet, when I run `php bin/phpunit`, I get:

```
No tests executed!
```

Anybody knows why? I am on Symfony 4 and PHPUnit 6.5.5

**Update**

Here is my `phpunit.xml/dist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test" />
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="1" />
        <env name="APP_SECRET" value="s$cretf0rt3st" />
        <env name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
        <!-- define your env variables for the test env here -->
        <env name="DATABASE_URL" value="postgresql://..." />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>./src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

In my `composer.json`:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
}
```

**More Findings**

When I implement a controller test class using the same namespace as in `\src`, it is detected and the same tests are performed !!! What is happening here?

Comment: can you post the `phpunit.xml` files? In which path the test file is located?

Comment: I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: the test folder is under tests folder. check the composer.json files in order to check the autoloader dir

Comment: It seems ok, I have updated my question again.

Comment: sure seems all fine, so the files should be `tests/ApplicationAvailabilityFunctionalTest.php`

Comment: That's what it is...

Answer (score 0):

I use VSCode, PHPUnit 4.0.2 plugin from Elon Mallin, phpunit-9.0.1.phar.

When I add * @test to my test, 'No tests executed!' problem was solved.

/**
   * @test
   * @dataProvider environmentVariables
   * 
   */
  public function get_client_ip_return_the_assert_When_Environment_The_Variable_Is_Found($env, $assert)
  {...

OK (6 tests, 6 assertions)

It is may be an oversight in the documentation https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.0/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit-data-providers.